# Remove 2 chars before dot in filename

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have lot of files name in folder  like `xxxxxxxxx.zip`

How can I remove for all the files the last 2 chars before the dot, with shell script.

For example `abcd12345678.zip` to `abcd123456.zip`

Comment: Welcome to the site. Since the syntax and available builtin features for text processing can vary substantially, please indicate _which_ shell (`bash`, `zsh`, ...) you are using. Also, please indicate OS flavor and version, the availability of external text-processing tools may depend on it.

Comment: @AdminBee Using Parameter expansion is portable and not that dificult. should work on most shells and most OS.

Answer (score 3):

Inside the shell, you can use variable expansions.

If fname contains the filename (`abcd12345678.zip` for example), you can do:

```bsh
fname=abcd12345678.zip
ftail=${fname##*.}
fnew=${fname%??".$ftail"}

echo mv "$fname" "$fnew.$ftail"
```

To process all files in one directory (checking if file already exists):

```bsh
for fname in *.zip; do
    ftail=${fname##*.}
    fnew="${fname%??".$ftail"}.$ftail"

    if [ -e "$fnew" ]; then
        echo "File $fnew already exist, not moving"
    else
        echo mv "$fname" "$fnew"
    fi
done
```

Remove the `echo` in front of `echo mv ....` to actually move files when you are confident that it will work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

What about `rename`?

```
rename 's/..\././g' abcd12345678.zip
```

Syntaxis is the same than `sed`'s one.

Comment: Note that it removes 2 bytes (not characters, and to the exclusion of `\n`, though it won't make a difference with that example) before the *first* occurrence of `.` in the file name (as long as that first occurrence has at least 2 non-`\n` bytes before it). For example, it would change a UTF-8 `áćéǵ.123456.zip` to `áćé.123456.zip` as that `ǵ` character is made of 2 bytes.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas you are right. I think it can be improved by adding the extension in the regex, so it would be 's/..\.zip/.zip/g'

Comment: Or `s/..\.zip\z/.zip/` so the `.zip` is only looked for at the end. Or `s/(.*)..\./$1./s`.

Answer (score 0):

The popular Bash shell allows testing for regexes with the `=~` operator in the `[[` test. Assuming variable `f` contains this:

```
$ echo "$f"
abcd12345678.zip
```

You can match out the last digits this way:

```
$ [[ "$f" =~ (.*)..\.zip ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}".zip
abcd123456.zip
```

Or even this way to make it more abstract:

```
$ [[ "$f" =~ (.*)..(\.zip) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}""${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
```

To rename use `mv`.

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload -Uz zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv -n '(*)??(.*)' '$1$2'
```

Remove the `-n` (for dry-run) when happy.

In cases where the file name contains more than one dot, that removes 2 characters before the last one.